# Query to get ORACLE_HOME path in Oracle 11G

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

Can anyone help me out with an PL/SQL query to get the ORACLE_HOME path in Oracle 11G?

I require it to be fetched from the Oracle DB only & not via the Operating system's environment variables.

PS: I'm a DB newbie.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Answer (score 6):

There is  [sys_context function](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions199.htm#SQLRF06117)

that works for Oracle 12c

```
select SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV','ORACLE_HOME') from dual;
```

This does not work for lower versions of Oracle.
For 11g and lower versions, I don't know a simple method.

PS: I read @Balasz' [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/97396/2047) and now I know a simple answer for version 11g.

Comment: The link to `sys_context` is not right. Please correct it.

Comment: @KaushikNayakk thnx

Answer (score 3):

```
SQL> select * from v$version;

BANNER
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
CORE    11.2.0.4.0      Production
TNS for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production

SQL> var oracle_home clob;
SQL> exec dbms_system.get_env('ORACLE_HOME', :oracle_home);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> print oracle_home

ORACLE_HOME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/oracle/base/product/db11204ee
```

But you want it in a query. This later version also allows you to grant execute just on this single function to users with lower privileges, instead of the whole DBMS_SYSTEM package:

```
create or replace function get_oracle_home return clob
as
  oh clob;
begin
  dbms_system.get_env('ORACLE_HOME', oh);
  return oh;
end;
/

SQL> select get_oracle_home from dual;

GET_ORACLE_HOME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/oracle/base/product/db11204ee
```

Comment: if you will give "ps -ef |grep tns" then get all details about your Oracle_Home

Comment: @Md Haidar Ali Khan: Even if the listener runs from the same Oracle Home, you can do this only on the database server itself.